# Problem with QGIS - Attribute names are shown as _1,_2,_3 ... and Strings are displayed as "NULL"

Tags: qgis

Whenever I look at the attribute table or at the attribute dialog for a shape, the attribute names are shown as _1,_2,_3, ... In the attributes, Strings are generally displayed as "NULL". Numbers are fine.

[image]

This happens to all shapefiles and it has not been a Problem in the beginning but at some point it startet. I unintalled Qgis several times and reinstalled different versions (2.2,2.6,2.8) from different sources (Ubuntu repositories, QGIS repositories) ... the problem remained. I also uninstalled grass libraries ... the problem remained. I reinstalled QT ... the problem remained. Any suggestion?

With that problem, QGIS is hardly usable :(

I'm using Ubuntu 64-bit. The problem startet under version 14.04, but survived an update to 14.10.

In the message window, I found one warning by python:

```
warning:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/uiparser.py:890: PendingDeprecationWarning: This method will be removed in future versions. Use 'elem.iter()' or 'list(elem.iter())' instead.

for include in elem.getiterator("include"):

traceback: File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 219, in startPlugin

plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)

File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/MetaSearch/__init__.py", line 28, in classFactory

from MetaSearch.plugin import MetaSearchPlugin

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import

mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/MetaSearch/plugin.py", line 31, in <module>

from MetaSearch.dialogs.maindialog import MetaSearchDialog

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import

mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/MetaSearch/dialogs/maindialog.py", line 49, in <module>

from MetaSearch.dialogs.manageconnectionsdialog import ManageConnectionsDialog

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import

mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/MetaSearch/dialogs/manageconnectionsdialog.py", line 39, in <module>

BASE_CLASS = get_ui_class('manageconnectionsdialog.ui')

File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/MetaSearch/util.py", line 59, in get_ui_class

return loadUiType(ui_file_full)[0]

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/__init__.py", line 210, in loadUiType

winfo = compiler.UICompiler().compileUi(uifile, code_string, from_imports, resource_suffix)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/compiler.py", line 139, in compileUi

w = self.parse(input_stream, resource_suffix)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/uiparser.py", line 992, in parse

actor(elem)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/uiparser.py", line 890, in readResources

for include in elem.getiterator("include"):
```

I don't think that this causes the problem, but I don't know.

Comment: Can you share one of the Shapefiles which exhibit this behavior?

Comment: First of all, here is a picture of how it looks like:
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-26274655/Tunesia.jpg.html

Comment: And second: The shapefiles are not broken! I tried at Computers from my colleauges who share the same configuration and everything is fine. Also doing a dbfdump gives the correct attribute names and Strings are shown normally. So the link dbf-qgis is somehow broken?

Comment: And thirdly: can I atttached a file here?

Comment: No, you need to use some file sharing service or Dropbox or Google Drive and paste the link here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't recall seeing or reading about an issue like this and it makes no sense to me. Maybe if nobody here can come up with an explanation try the QGIS user mailing list for further exposure.

Comment: Ok, I found something more strange. I create a new layer-file, I add a polygon and then I try to add an attribute to the (empty) attribute table. I get:

`   Errors: SUCCESS: 1 attribute(s) added.
      ERROR: field with index 1 is not the same!
      Provider: ogr
      Storage: ESRI Shapefile
      expected field: name=bla type=QString typeName=string len=30 precision=0
      retrieved field: name=_1 type=QString typeName= len=30 precision=0` Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution. Somehow qgis used the wrong encoding for the shapefiles I use. I switches t to UFT-8 and now everything is displayed correctly.